# What does the "last seen" status in WhatsApp stand for?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My boyfriend's phone is shown to me as "Last seen at 22.57 pm". I last spoke to him at 20.40pm. He tells me he stays online and doesn't close the app.

So what does the "last seen" stand for then? Is it the time he finally lost his signal or signed off -- or the last time he actively use the app chatting with someone?

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. I'm assuming you are using Whatsapp. So I would suggest you go to this site. http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/20971848

Comment: I also don't see the connection between your question and the tags used: what has your issue to do with email or the playstore? And how is it specific to Android 4.0? If it's about Whatsapp (as Akas assumes), there's a whatsapp-messenger tag available which would fit better. Same applies to Google Talk.

Comment: After the re-phrasing (which still matches the original, very emotional question), this looks like a completely valid question to me -- as trivial as the answer might seem ("last seen" = "last online"; it's the status of the app/connection, not of the user/activity ;)

Answer (score 3):

From WhatsApp's [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848):

> "Online" and "Last seen at" are timestamps that tell you whether
>   that your contacts are online, or the last time they were connected to
>   WhatsApp. "Last seen at" refers to the time the contact left WhatsApp.
>   You can also think of this as "Went offline at"

So having the app open would still show you as "Online", but does not mean that any messages are being sent. Note that even then, [the timestamp might still be incorrect](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21555253).

Answer (score 0):

The Whatsapp last seen timing is actually when was the last time the contact was seen online, or last used Whatsapp. It is a time stamp that is generated by the Whatsapp server.

There are actually apps that track last seen timings of contacts, like this one called [Spyder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebuildlabs.beanstalk&hl=en). It's pretty cool! It is like an MSN console that shows which of your friends are online right now!